# Proto compiler fails on MacOS Big Sur

Tags: python, python-3.x, grpc, grpc-python

To replicate:
Created a Conda environment with Python3.9 on MacOS Big Sur and install gRPC for Python:

```
conda create -n grpc python=3.9
conda activate grpc
pip3 install grpcio grpcio-tools
```

After this, I wrote a proto file to define a service. So a sample file like:

```
package unary;

service Unary{
  // A simple RPC.
  //
  // Obtains the MessageResponse at a given position.
 rpc GetServerResponse(Message) returns (MessageResponse) {}

}

message Message{
 string message = 1;
}

message MessageResponse{
 string message = 1;
 bool received = 2;
}
```

and when I tried compiling with the following command:

```
python3 -m grpc_tools.protoc ./proto/service/service.proto --python_out=./proto/python --grpc_python_out=./proto/python
```

it gave me the following output

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.5/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/grpc_tools/protoc.py", line 22, in <module>
    from grpc_tools import _protoc_compiler
ImportError: dlopen(/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/grpc_tools/_protoc_compiler.cpython-39-darwin.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
        /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/grpc_tools/_protoc_compiler.cpython-39-darwin.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
        /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.9/site-packages/grpc_tools/_protoc_compiler.cpython-39-darwin.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

Why is this happening, and how can I fix it? Any help regarding why this is happening would be very helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using M1, I would recommend to read this comment for how to use our precompiled wheels: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/25082#issuecomment-754718296.

If not, you might mixed the Python3.9 owned by macOS and the Python binary owned by Conda.